# Advanced FInd and Replace Question

Tags: wine, libreoffice

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS very happily on an old Compaq610. I am NOT a techie, but my son, about to finish his degree in Computer Science has helped me quite a lot. Ubuntu has been great so far, even to this old guy who didn't grow up around computers. The first hard drive I saw was 512kb, it weighed about 35kg and was the size of a suitcase - I first sat at a PC long after I completed school.

I am compiling an ISO9001 QMS for my (very lean) startup from a free template by Oxebridge.
It urecommends Abacre Advanced Find and Replace to populate the myriad document templates with my company name etc.

The Oxebridge manual DOES stipulate use of MSOffice.

I was able to open and edit the .csv Matrix file with something I installed (I forget the name now - but it was gnu-something) and LibreOffice.

When I try to run Advanced FAR (in WINE) it doesn't find any of the terms specified in the Matrix, never mind replace anything. It says searching but at bottom left of the screen it says (small) 0 found in (say)110msecs. And it just hangs there....

I have a little experience with the sudo apt-get kind of commands, but not really a lot.

I started a thread on the Oxebridge forum asking if anyone had done the ISO9001 manual from Oxebridge template on  Ubuntu before...but no responses.

Can another FAR app run in place of the Abacre one? 
WHich one would be best?
Is there a way to make the Abacre app run properly?

Does anyone have any suggestions for a non-tech?

Best regards from Cape Town....